# sql server Min, Max range

Tags: max, distinct, min

I have a huge table

startip endip country
1111    2000   in
2001    3000   in
3001    4000   in
4001    5000   chi
5001    6000   chi

I want to merge all these rows like

startip endip country
1111    4000  in
4001    6000  chi

I want do this in sqlserver. 
Min(start_ip) , Max(end_ip) for DISTINCT(country) 
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`.
For example:

```
SELECT country, MIN(start_ip), MAX(end_ip)
FROM a_table
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: I have case like 100 200 india , 201 300 india , 301 400 china, 401 500 india , so min and max gives 100 - 500 india , which is wrong. Any help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your table schema looks like but I think what you're trying to achieve will be accomplished using **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT country, MIN(start_ip), MAX(end_ip) FROM your_table
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: I have case like 100 200 india , 201 300 india , 301 400 china, 401 500 india , so min and max gives 100 - 500 india , which is wrong. Any help